# Algorithm for finding Eigenvectors given Eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to find the best OOBB hitboxes for my meshes using PCA. In order to do this, I need the eigenvectors but I am kind of lost how to compute them without using a huge library.

I implemented an algorithm that computes three eigenvalues given a 3x3 Matrix. The code for this originally is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3%C3%973_matrices):

```
private Vector3 CalculateEigenvalues(ref Matrix3 A)
{
    Vector3 val = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    float p1 = A.M12 * A.M12 + A.M13 * A.M13 + A.M23 * A.M23;
    if (p1 == 0)
    {
        val.X = A.M11;
        val.Y = A.M22;
        val.Z = A.M33;
    }
    else
    {
        float q = A.Trace / 3f;
        float p2 = (float)(Math.Pow(A.M11 - q, 2) + Math.Pow(A.M22 - q, 2) + Math.Pow(A.M33 - q, 2)) + 2 * p1;
        float p = (float)Math.Sqrt(p2 / 6);
        Matrix4 I = Matrix4.Identity;
        Matrix4.Mult(ref I, q, out Matrix4 tmp);
        Matrix4 tmp2 = Matrix4.Subtract(new Matrix4(A), tmp);
        Matrix4 B = Matrix4.Mult(tmp2, 1 / p);
        float r = new Matrix3(B).Determinant / 2;

        float phi = 0;
        if (r <= -1)
            phi = (float)Math.PI / 3;
        else if (r >= 1)
            phi = 0;
        else
            phi = (float)Math.Acos(r) / 3;
        val.X = q + 2 * p * (float)Math.Cos(phi);
        val.Z = q + 2 * p * (float)Math.Cos(phi + (2 * Math.PI / 3));
        val.Y = 3 * q - val.X - val.Z;
    }
    return val;
}
```

However, the Wikipedia article has no code for calculating the eigenvectors for the three eigenvalues. I tried to understand this topic, but my math skills are quite limited. I would have to google every second word in every tutorial.

**So my question is:**

If I have the 3x3 matrix and three eigenvalues, is there any simple way to compute the corresponding eigenvectors without using external libraries?

Comment: You need to solve a system of three linear equation. That's a pretty straightforward task per se but requires some coding.

Comment: Ok I think I can come up with an algorithm to solve a three linear equation system. But how do I know which equations to put into that?

Comment: For each eigenvalue **λ** the corresponding eigenvector **v** is the solution to **Av = λv**.  That expands into 3 equations -- one for each component of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely simple implementation for the case when all eigenvalues have the same [algebraic and geometric](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk10/10_algebraic_and_geometric_multiplicities.html) multiplicities (which is the case with rotation matrices) is like this:

```
// Observe that the function doesn't use rZ,
// it is expected that it will become zero vector in triangular form
static Vector3 EigenVector(Vector3 rX, Vector3 rY, Vector3 rZ, float lambda)
{
    // Move RHS to LHS
    rX.X -= lambda;
    rY.Y -= lambda;
    // Transform to upper triangle
    rY -= rX * (rY.X / rX.X);
    // Backsubstitute
    var res = new Vector3(1f);
    res.Y = -rY.Z / rY.Y;
    res.X = -(rX.Y * res.Y + rX.Z * res.Z) / rX.X;
    return res;
}

// Case of eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity two
static (Vector3, Vector3) EigenVector2(Vector3 rX, Vector3 rY, Vector3 rZ, float lambda)
{
    // Move RHS to LHS
    rX.X -= lambda;
    float x2 = rX.Y / rX.X;
    float x3 = rX.Z / rX.X;
    return (new Vector3(x2, 1, 0), new Vector3(x3, 0, 1));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rX = new Vector3(1, -3, 3);
    var rY = new Vector3(3, -5, 3);
    var rZ = new Vector3(6, -6, 4);
    var e = EigenVector(rX, rY, rZ, 4);
    var e2 = EigenVector2(rX, rY, rZ, 2);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e2.Item1.ToString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e2.Item2.ToString());
}
```

> <0,5  0,5  1>
>   <3  1  0>
>   <-3  0  1>

In real life, one needs to make a lot of error checking. Input data is taken from [this paper](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~dahyotr/CS1BA1/SolutionEigen.pdf).

Comment: So the lamdba is one eigenvalue and rX, rY and rZ vectors are the rows of the matrix? Or its columns?

Comment: @3DLearner yes, lambda is an eigenvalue and rX, rY, rZ - rows, i haven't found Matrix3 class in C#.

Comment: thank you! I will test this. I will get back to you when I'm done testing. By the way: the Matrix3 class is from the OpenTK library I use for OpenGL in C#.

Comment: In your implementation, you need to check for division by zero. Say, if in the first function rX.X is very close to zero you need to swap rows. Algorithms like this can easily become numerically unstable. If you need to do more maths you might be better off using external well tested library. And it will help you to build your application faster and don't be drown by gory details.

Comment: since I asked for the simplest way to do this, I gladly mark this question as solved. Thank you very much for your help! I finally have better Hitboxes now ;-)